# Error in sending SMTP mail

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, smtp-auth

Try to send mail from window server using SMTP.
and i get this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in...
```

and when i use PHPmailerAutoload.php only then it gives

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SMTP::setDebugLevel() in...
```

My code is

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
include("class.smtp.php"); 

$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Host       = "mail.host.com.au";
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->Username   = "myusername";
$mail->Password   = "mypassword";
$mail->SetFrom('info@company.com.au', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo("info@company.com.au","First Last");
$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject";
$body             = "test";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Please provide any suggestion.

Comment: you missed `"` in this line replace  `$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject";`

Comment: set SMTPDebug  to false `$mail->SMTPDebug = false;`

Comment: Nothing happened same error is showing...

Comment: my code was perfect, then i read in google that there are several versions of phpmailer class available, so i tried with different version and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: There is only one supported version of PHPMailer, and it's on GitHub. All others are old or fake.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem doing this.. and i resolved it..
Open your PHPMailer and in that class.phpmailer.php and in that add this line at the starting in the php block: require_once('class.smtp.php');
It'll surely work.. or you can download that two files from this link:
https://github.com/abhishekpanjabi/e-Legal.git

Download phpmailer it has only two requird files and replace it with your phpmailer's files.. it'll work  [I've uploded image showing code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXhaA.png)

Comment: i have added in the file class.phpmailer.php, but it says now "Fatal error: Call to undefined method SMTP::setTimeout() in..."

Comment: i can not open your github link. can you please check it.

Comment: have you removed include("class.smtp.php") from this code you've shown above ??

Comment: my code was perfect, then i read in google that there are several versions of phpmailer class available, so i tried with different version and it worked.

Comment: i can open this github link.. and it works fine.. i tried frrom 3 different browsers and i worked..don't know what is the problem with yours.

Comment: Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: That's how to "fix" it if you don't understand autoloaders. Read the docs and do it properly.